# why does $|r'|^2 = r'^2 + r^2\theta^{\prime2}$?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

For a particle moving in 3 dimensions. I know Angular momentum is $mr^2θ$ in the z dimension

edit: not sure how to do absolute value in math terms

here is some more info Consider a particle moving in three dimensions with no force.
I think its motion is $ r = rcosθ x + rsinθ y + 0z $

Comment: Is this for motion under a radial force, thus conserving angular momentum?

Comment: You can find math formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This question probably belongs on physics stack exchange.  Also, it needs more context.  Give the definitions of all your variables when asking physics problems.

Comment: i added more information that i got

Comment: With no force the motion is linear. I've posted an answer that addresses a more general case. (It does use the angular momentum being nonzero, but even the linear case achieves that if the origin is chosen outside the linear path.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under a radial force, motion is confined to a plane orthogonal to the conserved angular momentum. Polar coordinates in that plane satisfy$$\vec{r}=r\hat{r}\implies\vec{r}^\prime=r^\prime\vec{r}+r\hat{r}^\prime.$$Since $\hat{r}=\hat{i}\cos\theta+\hat{j}\sin\theta$, $\frac{d\hat{r}}{d\theta}=-\hat{i}\sin\theta+\hat{j}\cos\theta$ is orthogoanl to $\hat{r}$, and$$\hat{r}^\prime=\theta^\prime\frac{d\hat{r}}{d\theta}\implies\vec{r}^\prime\cdot\vec{r}^\prime=r^{\prime2}+r^2\theta^{\prime2}.$$